# call AWS POST API with AWS Signature Version 4

Tags: datastage

did someone already called an AWS  Rest API  with AWS Signature Version 4 ?
I'm not sure how to generate this using the hierarchical stage Calling the Rest API  ?
Thank You -

Answer (score 0):

what do you mean by hierarchical stage, do you want to build the whole signature on your own?

Which language are you trying to call it with? There are different packages depending on that, I highly recommend using one of those instead of rebuilding it on your own.

[agnostic-aws-signature](https://www.npmjs.com/package/agnostic-aws-signature) This worked for me for example...